# How to run a server application on Windows iot core using an background application template

Tags: raspberry-pi3, asp.net-core-2.0, windows-10-iot-core, .net-standard-2.0

I'm trying to host an asp.net core 2.0 web API in an IBackgroundTask. The background task is deployed on an raspberry pi 3 running Windows 10 iot core build 16299.

My setup has two projects:

1. Windows iot background application for hosting the API.
2. One .net standard 2.0 class library which contains the controller and the startup class.

For the background application I've checked the capabilities:

- internetClient
- internetClientServer
- privateNetworkClientServer

I'm running the Kestrel server with the following code:

```
public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
{
    var deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
    using (var host = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()                
                             .UseStartup<Startup>()
                             .UseUrls("http://*:5001")
                             .Build())
        host.Run();
    deferral.Complete();
}
```

And opened the ports using the following PowerShell command:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="FezHat.Web.Api" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=5001
```

But the following exception is thrown:

> System.IO.IOException: 'Failed to bind to address http://[::]:5001: address already in use.'

I've tried different port numbers, but the exception keeps throwing.
When I host the API from an .net core console application on my PC the API works.

How can I host the API from an iot background application on an raspberry pi 3?

Comment: How do you make `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()` API work on UWP? Do you use an additional library?

Comment: It's from the nuget package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions

Comment: It has IWebHost not WebHost.

Comment: Sorry, Webhost is from Microsoft.AspNetCore.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an errant instance continuing to run from a previous debug session that isn't disposed properly. I would check out [Microsoft Message Analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/manage-your-device/networkpacketcapture) though. It's been very helpful to me.